If an electron is inside an atom, does the expected value of spin measurements also depend on the orbital wavefunction?
The total quantum state of an electron in an atom can be written as the product of the orbital wavefunction and a spinor representing its spin state, $\Psi = \psi(r,\theta,\phi) \otimes \chi$. Say you want to measure the $z$ component of spin with the operator $S_z$. The expected value would be $\langle\Psi|S_z|\Psi\rangle$. Say that the spin state is an eigenstate of $S_z$ with $\hbar/2$. Then, assuming a hydrogen (or hydrogen-like) atom:
$$\langle S_z\rangle_\Psi = \frac{\hbar}{2} |R_{nl}Y_{lm}|^2$$
And therefore the expected value would depend on the quantum state of the electron within the atom. Is this a logical conclusion?

No. You must integrate over all other coordinates. I.e., you have to take the expectation value of $I\otimes S_z$, where $I$ is the identity operator on (here) $L^2(\mathbb R^3)$. Your expression for the expected value is mathematically not well-defined, because $S_z$ only acts on (here) $\mathbb C^2$.

Alright, so that just leaves the normalization of the spatial wavefunction which is one. Thanks.
